# Timer - How to stop it? AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-builder, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I am learning how to make a timer to my game. It is something like "Who wants to be a millionaire?" I have 15 questions. There is timer for each question:60 seconds.... When I click on an answer I go on next frame, but my timer does not stop. What should I add ( and where ) to stop my timer when I clik an answer? (Flash Professional CS 5/ ActionScript 2) My code for the timer is:

```
timer = 60;

    countdown = function(){
    _root.timer--;
    if(_root.timer<=0){
      gotoAndPlay(20); stop();
    }
    }
    countdownInterval = setInterval(countdown,1000);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer();

public function startTimer(n:Number):void{ //n = number of seconds you want to run the timer
   t.repeatCount = n;
   t.start();
   t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerComplete);
}

public function timerComplete(event:TimerEvent):void{
   t.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerComplete);

   //What ever you want to do when timer is up.
}
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: @AndrewBramwell Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line just before your `nextFrame()`code or the call to `gotoAndPlay(20);`

```
clearInterval(countdownInterval);
```

Hope this helps (if you still need it)

[See Here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000556.html)

Comment: would somebody care to explain why this has been marked down? to my knowledge the question was how to stop an AS2 timer, my answer is the simplest way to stop and AS2 Timer...